# unittest, mock time.sleep in other package

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, import, mocking, sleep

I have a Pycharm project with some package code under test and i can import the package like `import my_package` from another module in the project as Pycharm configures python to include the projectdir into it's search path.
The `my_module` in `my_package` imports `time` and uses `time.sleep`, which i want to mock out.

```
projectdir/my_package
  __init__.py
  my_module.py

projectdir/tests
  test_my_package.py
```

In the test I have the following code:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_package import my_module


@patch("my_package.my_module.time.sleep")
class TestMyPackage(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bla(self, timepatch):
        my_module.my_function()
```

The problem I have is, that the `time.sleep` is not mocked out. My unittests need about 0.5s per testcase which i way too much. I guess I'm patching at the wrong spot.
Can you help me fix the `@patch("my_package.my_module.time.sleep")` decorator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By experimenting I found the answer. I had to use

```
sleeppatch = patch("my_package.my_module.time.sleep")
sleeppatch.start()
```

within the `setUp` method of the testclass
and:

```
sleeppatch.stop()
```

in the `tearDown` method.

Using the decoration, the patch was stopped too early.